# Replace item letters in enumerate with FontAwesome icons

Tags: lists, enumerate, fontawesome, icon

**Problem:**

Removing all color related mechanisms from LaTex code to replace enumerate letters with FontAwesome icons. I have managed to show the icons but can't seem to get rid of the colors in the code.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}


\definecolor{editorWhite}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorBlack}{cmyk}{1, 1, 1, 1}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\usageitem}[3][black]{%
  \item[%
    \colorbox{#2}{{\makebox[2em]{\strut #3}}}%
  ]
}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=12mm}

\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=6pt,topsep=6pt]
  \usageitem{editorWhite}{\centering \faBook} \textbf{Dictionary} is ...
  \usageitem{editorWhite}{\centering \large \faYoutubePlay} \textbf{Mobile phones} are cool ...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

**Desired output:**

Get rid of all color related mechanisms (definecolor, colorbox, black) and keep layout intact.

Comment: This isn't an `enumerate` list any longer, you should rather use `description`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Excellent, this worked out well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you expect something like this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\usageitem}[1]{%
  \item[%
    {\makebox[2em]{\strut #1}}%
  ]
}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=12mm}

\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=6pt,topsep=6pt]
  \usageitem{\centering \faBook} \textbf{Dictionary} is ...
  \usageitem{\centering \large \faYoutubePlay} \textbf{Mobile phones} are cool ...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

All I did: removed the xcolor-related commands (note: compiled using lualatex).

Answer (score 1):

I followed the recommendation by @Christian and came up with this solution that supports (1) the use of FontAwesome icons in `description` lists (2) centering icons in labels based on the largest width of the icon used and, (3) indent icons and text through the `labelindent` option.

Highly appreciate everyone's effort.

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\langicons}
\setlength{\langicons}{\widthof{\faEnvelopeO}}
\addtolength{\langicons}{\labelsep}
\SetLabelAlign{CenterWithParen}{\makebox[\langicons]{#1}}

\begin{description}[
            itemsep=1em, 
            topsep=6pt, 
            parsep=0pt, 
            partopsep=0pt, 
            labelwidth=\langicons, 
            itemindent=0cm, 
            leftmargin=!, 
            rightmargin=0cm, 
            align=CenterWithParen, 
            labelindent=0em
]
  \item[\faSearch] \textbf{Search engines} can use ...
  \item[\faLanguage] \textbf{Proofreading} can be ...
  \item[\large \faCommentsO] \textbf{Translation tools} can use ...
\end{description}

\end{document}
```